# Ping pong mechanism in Netty websocket client - send ping frame every 5 minutes

Tags: netty

I have a client application which receives messages from Websocket server.

If I have to ping the server once after every 5minutes of inactivity, how to do this?
I am trying to use Netty timer to do this.

```
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
            Channel ch = ctx.channel();
            WebSocketFrame frame = (WebSocketFrame)msg;
            if ((frame instanceof BinaryWebSocketFrame)) {
                BinaryWebSocketFrame binaryWebSocketFrame = (BinaryWebSocketFrame)frame;
                ByteBuf buffer = binaryWebSocketFrame.content();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.readableBytes()];
                buffer.getBytes(0, bytes);
                String data = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
                JsonObject jsonObject = this.jsonParser.parse(data).getAsJsonObject();

                //ch.write(new PingWebSocketFrame()); //How to send ping every 5minutes. Is this the right place to send the ping message?

               //Is the below code a right way to of using the Timer:
                **Timer timer = new Timer() {
                @Override
                public Timeout newTimeout(TimerTask timerTask, long l, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
                    //return null;
                    TimerTask task = timeout -> ch.write(new PingWebSocketFrame(buffer));
                    return newTimeout(task, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                }
                @Override
                public Set<Timeout> stop() {
                    return null;
                    }
                };
                TimerTask task = timeout -> ch.write(new PingWebSocketFrame(buffer));
                timer.newTimeout(task, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);**

            }
            else if ((frame instanceof PingWebSocketFrame)) {
                frame.content().retain();
                ch.writeAndFlush(new PongWebSocketFrame(frame.content()));
                //return;
            }
            else if ((frame instanceof PongWebSocketFrame)) {
                System.out.println("WebSocket Client received pong");
            }
            else if ((frame instanceof CloseWebSocketFrame)) {
                ch.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ctx.executor().schedule(...)` for this. Beside this you could also use `IdleStateHandler` and have it emit a `IdleStateEvent` if there were no activity for 5 minutes. Then you can intercept this event and trigger a write.

Comment: `Runnable runnable = () -> ch.write(new PingWebSocketFrame(buffer)); ctx.executor().schedule(runnable, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);`
I will replace the timer code with this code block and try

Comment: you should use `writeAndFlush(...)`

Comment: Will the executor schedule reset the time to 5minutes when a new message comes in?

Comment: nope... for this you should better use `IdleStateHandler` which can do this.

Comment: @NormanMaurer, I have successfully caught the `IdleStateEvent` event in `userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt)` of my customized `impleChannelInboundHandler<StompFrame>`, Is there a way to get the event itself and get the actual StompFrame message at the same time, so I can get the information on message header to tell which client is idling?